# Disallow copy constructor but allow implicit copy from other type

Tags: c++, class, c++11, copy-constructor

Here is my code, I disable the copy constructor, but it also disables my implicit copy from other types. Any work around in this case ?

Tested on: g++ (GCC) 4.7.1

```
struct item {
  int b;
};

class test {
 public:
  test(const test& copy) = delete;

  test(const item& a) {
    std::cout << "OK " << a.b << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  test a = item{10}; //error: use of deleted function ‘test::test(const test&)’
}
```

Comment: Give `test` a move constructor if you can, or use the direct initialization syntax if you can't.

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using ?

Comment: @IanCook: added the version

Comment: Curiously gcc & clang both give an error but MSVC2013 compiles it fine. I don't know my way around the standard well enough to know which is correct.

Comment: @Ian I'm pretty sure it's an MSVC extension.

Comment: @remyabel It's not a valid conforming extension. The difference here is easily observable with `std::is_convertible`, which means that it can alter the behavior of well-formed code. (It also compiles in MSVC with `/Za` (disable extensions), so it's more likely to be a bug...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either give `test` a move constructor:

```
test(test&&) = default;
```

or use direct initialization:

```
test a{item{10}};
```

There's no other workaround. Copy-initialization where destination type is a class type, such as `test a = item{10};`, always requires a callable copy or move constructor.

---

The relevant rule is specified in §8.5 [dcl.init]/p17:

> If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> - If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source
>     type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the
>     destination, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors
>     are enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best one is chosen through overload
>     resolution (13.3). The constructor so selected is called to initialize
>     the object, with the initializer expression or *expression-list* as its
>     argument(s). If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is
>     ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.
> - Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source
>     type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used)
>     to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4,
>     and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3). If the
>     conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the initialization is
>     ill-formed. The function selected is called with the initializer
>     expression as its argument; if the function is a constructor, the call
>     initializes a temporary of the cv-unqualified version of the
>     destination type. The temporary is a prvalue. The result of the call
>     (which is the temporary for the constructor case) is then used to
>     direct-initialize, according to the rules above, the object that is
>     the destination of the copy-initialization. In certain cases, an
>     implementation is permitted to eliminate the copying inherent in this
>     direct-initialization by constructing the intermediate result directly
>     into the object being initialized; see 12.2, 12.8.

The source type is `item`, the destination type is `test`, it's copy initialization, so it falls under the second bullet point. There's only one available conversion using the `test(const item& a)` constructor, so a prvalue temporary of type `test` is constructed from the `item` and then used to direct-initialize the destination in accordance with the first bullet point. This, in turn, must call a constructor of `test` that can accept a `const test &` or `test &&` argument. Even if the copy or move is elided, you still must have such a constructor available.

Comment: move constructor does the job! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are three options I can think of:

1) Move constructor
2) Assignment operator + default constructor
3) Calling the constructor explicitly

```
#include <iostream>

struct item {
    int b;
};
struct test {
    test(const test& copy) = delete;
    test(const item& a) {
        std::cout << "OK " << a.b << std::endl;
    }
//  move:
    test(test&& from) {}
//  added:
    test() {}
    test& operator = (const test& src) = default;
};

int main() {
//fine after move constructor:
    test a = item{10};
//all fine with original
    test b(item{20});
//fine after adding .ctor() and op=
    test c; c = item{30};
}
```